# Giving a `<span>` a negative vertical margin

Tags: html, css, margin

Why can't a `<span>` have a negative vertical margin or padding?

If I set it to `display: block`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: A `span` can have a negative margin: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/WjRbb/. Padding does not support negative values.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem.  negative margins should work for spans as long as they have display:block set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your browser does not support this feature?
A negative margin for `span` is possible. Such a simple example works for me in Firefox and Chrome:

```
<span style="display:block; margin-left:-20px;">My text.</span>
```

Comment: sorry correction - it won't support a negative VERTICAL margin

Comment: Which browser are you using? `<span style="display:block; margin-top:-20px;">My text.</span>` also works for vertical margin (in Firefox and Chrome).

Answer (score 4):

From the CSS 2.1 spec:

> ### 8.3 Margin properties: 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'
>
> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The
>   'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while
>   the other margin properties only set their respective side. These
>   properties apply to all elements, but **vertical margins will not have
>   any effect on non-replaced inline elements.**

`<span>` is, by default, a non-replaced inline element.

Also

> ### 8.4 Padding properties: 'padding-top', 'padding-right', 'padding-bottom', 'padding-left', and 'padding'
>
> ...
>
> Unlike margin properties, values for padding values cannot be
>   negative.